# How do I pass information between storyboard segues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

In the app I'm creating, one of the features is that users can submit their own quotes to be displayed in the app. There is one storyboard segue that lets the user enter their name, email and website, and then on the next they type in a quote and the app then posts all of this data to a database. I'm not sure how I can easily pass data from the first storyboard segue to the next, so that it can post all of the information to the database in one go. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method to pass data from the source to destination view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
        MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.myProperty1 = ...;
        controller.myProperty2 = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to access it in the destination view controller?