# Passing data to a view controller different when the controller is presented modally?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm pretty new with the iOS stuff, and thought I understood passing data to a view controller. Apparently not. I am trying to pass image data from a parent ViewController to a child ViewController that is presented modally. I think the problem has something to with the way objects are passed to a modally presented view controller instead of one pushed onto the navigation stack. Bellow is the code from the parent and the child related to the problems I am having.

From the Parent.m:

```
- (IBAction)sort:(id)sender {
    SortSelectViewController *ssvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sort"];
    ssvc.backgroundImage = [self screenshot];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sort" sender:self];
    //The segue is linked from my parent view controller to my child with the identifier "sort"

}

- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 20, 640, 1116);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    return image;
}
```

This is in my Child.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *backgroundImage;
```

This is my Child.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.backgroundImage);
    //This log will return nil when the program is run - clear sign data is not being correctly passed
    self.backgroundImage = [self.backgroundImage applyDarkEffect];
    self.imageView.image = self.backgroundImage;
}
```

I have imported my child view controller into my parent class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass information between storyboard segues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597025/how-do-i-pass-information-between-storyboard-segues)

Comment: Try to carry the image in app delegate and assign the image in child view controller in viewwillapper method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Like this By using Story Bord  Must use combination of two Methods **performSegueWithIdentifier:** **prepareForSegue:**

```
    - (IBAction)sort:(id)sender {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sort" sender:self];
        //The segue is linked from my parent view controller to my child with the identifier "sort"

    }



    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sort"])
        {
           SortSelectViewController *ssvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        ssvc.backgroundImage = [self screenshot];
        }
     }

- (UIImage *) screenshot {
       //return normal image 
    return [UIImage imagenamed:"imagename.png"];
}
```

Comment: EDIT: sorry I didn't change the method of initializing the view controller to that one. That works, but why can't I do it all from the button press?

Answer (score 1):

Your code (original question) is conflating direct instantiation of view controller and storyboard segues. When you use a storyboard segue, the VC is instantiated automatically *for* you. You access it as the "destination view controller" in the segue in "prepareForSegue:" method.

What's happening is that you instantiate a view controller, set the image, then… it gets thrown away and ignored (the entire vc).

Next, you initiate a segue, which iOS handles by instantiating *another*, different view controller. It's this view controller that iOS is presenting.

So: if you're going to use a Storyboard segue, iOS instantiates the VC for you. Don't instantiate one yourself, because there's no way to link the one *you* instantiate into the iOS segue handling. The one you instantiate is an irrelevant extra that gets ignored.