# How to Keep class alive between views?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have some Bluetooth class, that creates connection to a bluetooth module .
As long as this class is alive, the connection is alive .
We are creating that class instance, in `viewA` .
Than when we go to `viewB` ,we would like to keep the BL class alive, by passing it to the next view , `viewB` .

How would we do that (without singleton ,just passing it,or using app delegate)

in `viewA` :

```
//creating the instance of the BL class

   self.bluetooth=[[BLEModule alloc] init];
    self.bluetooth.delegate=self;
  ...
  ....
//go the next view-viewB (now pass that instance self.bluetooth to viewB)

        UIViewController *next=[[CallTestView alloc]init];
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [UIView transitionFromView:delegate.window.rootViewController.view
                            toView:next.view
                          duration:1.5f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             delegate.window.rootViewController=next;

         }];
```

Comment: You can do it by declaring your BL class as strong in appdelegate.h, (like-property(strong, nonatomic) BLEModule *bluetooth & alloc init at didfinishlaunching. this way you class will be alive throughout whole app. You can use it, where ever you want (like - appdelegate.bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

First, using the `AppDelegate` is kinda like a singleton (you keep a reference to one object that is initialized once, and you pass the reference to it when someone ask).

But to answer your question, you have a few ways you can accomplish this

1) delegation - `viewA` is a delegate of `viewB` and you can pass information between them. Check this out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

2) KVO - `viewB` registers to a "radio station" and listen to massages and `viewA` broadcast to that "radio station" , by that wat you can pass information between `viewA` and `viewB` (even between multiple views). Check this out [Link](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)

3) segue - you can pass information between `viewA` and `viewB` with the `segue` (if they are connected with one). Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597025/how-do-i-pass-information-between-storyboard-segues)

There are advantages and Disadvantages to every method above. You need to figure out what is best for your case

Comment: Thanks, but its actually not my question. I know what delegates are, and i know ways to pass data between views. My goal is that when viewA is dead, i will pass from viewA to the next view, an instance of the BL class, that was created in viewA . so right before viewA is dead, he will send the BL instance to the next view .

Comment: have you tried using viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear?